# docker image is not rebuilt automatically on file change

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, wsl-2, docker-image

I am running docker containers with WSL2. When I make changes to my files in the /client directory the changes are not reflected and I have to do `docker compose stop client`, `docker compose build client` and `docker compose start client`. If I `cat` a file after changing domething one can see the change.
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.17.0-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /client/node_modules
RUN chown -R node:node /client/node_modules
RUN chown -R node:node /root
WORKDIR /client

# Copy Files
COPY . .

# Install Dependencies
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install --force 

USER root
```

I alse have a /server directory with the following Dockerfile and the automatic image rebuild happens on file change there just fine:

```
FROM node:16.17.0-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /server/node_modules
RUN chown -R node:node /server/node_modules
WORKDIR /server

COPY . .

# Install Dependencies
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install --force --verbose

USER root
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Docker is not going to rebuild an image on a file change. I suspect you are really asking why *node* has not rebuilt/reacted/reloaded based on a source code file change?

Comment: i am fairly new to this so might be. Do you have any tips on how to fix the issue if it's node related?

Comment: I'd recommend running Node directly on the host, not inside an isolation system like Docker.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about the hot-reload in node. But if you are just developing then perhaps (as suggested by the @abo answer below) just run node locally. There are several existing questions that you could review to see if they help with your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=docker+node+not+reloading

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding the following to my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
environment:
    WATCHPACK_POLLING: "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker does not take care of the hot-reload.

You should look into the hot-reload documentation of the tools you are building with.

Comment: my colleague, who I am writing the app with is developing on MacOS and has no such issues. so hot-reload shouldn't be the problem.